# Python Scapy - Loading HTTP from a file

Tags: python, http, scapy

I'm using [this](https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http/blob/master/scapy_http/http.py) extension for scapy to detect and analyze HTTP packets. It works great, but when I save the HTTP packets to a pcap file with `wrpcap` and then load it with `rdpcap` it doesn't give me the same packet, it only detects its HTTP packet but not HTTP Requests, it also occurs when I do this -

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy_http.http import *

packets = sniff(count=10, lfilter=lambda p: HTTPRequest in p)
wrpcap('file.pcap', packets)
restored = rdpcap('file.pcap')
print len([x for x in restored if HTTPRequest in p]) # prints 0
```

Why this is happening? how can I recover the packets?

Comment: Well, youll most likely need to defragment and tcp reassemble the packets to reconstruct your http stream.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to Python in general, Scapy in particular but is this what you are looking for?

```
from scapy.all import *

def http_request(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer('HTTPRequest'):  ##Use HTTPResponse for response packets
        pkt.show()
        exit(0)  ##Omit to show more then the first packet

pkts = rdpcap('/root/Desktop/example_network_traffic.pcap')
for p in pkts:
    http_request(p)

##For sniffing packets
##sniff(prn=http_request)
```

I think the problem may be the way Scapy exorts packets.  When I run your code and inspect the packet in Wireshark, the protocol is listed as TCP.  When I use Wireshark to capture the same type of packet, it lists the protocol as HTTP.  If I export the packet from Wireshark and read it using rdpcap, you get the results you are looking for, ie the HTTPRequest/HTTPResponse layers.  I don't know this for fact, but I checked the [Berkeley Packet Filter syntax](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html), and they don't list HTTP as a protocol.  If Scapy is based on the BPF syntax, and they don't use the HTTP protocol, maybe it exports the packet with a protocol of TCP and Scapy-Http just parses the Raw load during sniff().  Just a guess.

Comment: no, my problem is that after saving a packet using wrpcap then rdpcap cannot recover the HTTPRequest layer.

Comment: Ok.  What does your script show?  Do you have an example?

Comment: I showed a better a example, look at the code and you will see